# como instalar una web en un vps

Tags: vps

Tengo una **VPS** y no logro que funcione (es la primera vez que hago esto)
**Mi .htaccess :**

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?miweb.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/root/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /root/$1 
  RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /miweb/index.html [L]
```

En **apache2** tengo (`/etc/apache2/sites-available`)

```
miweb.com.conf
```

Solo obtengo `index of` cuando la corro.

Comment: ¿Has usado `a2ensite miweb.com.conf` para habilitarlo?

Comment: Hola, si , me dice  already enabled

Comment: Bueno, ahora estoy pero creo..You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Y si te manod lo que tengo por mail y me ayudas?

Comment: Tendrá que ser mañana. Aquí son más de las 21h y toca descansar.

Comment: Yo soy de Argentina y vos ?

Comment: Yo logré configurar mi VPS siguiendo este [tutorial](https://diarioprogramador.com/configurar-vps-de-ionos-desde-cero)